# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str

Tags: python

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a[3] + "hello"
```

When I type this they show me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Can someone please explain what is happening?

Comment: Note also that Python list indices start at `0`,m so accessing index `3` on `[1, 2, 3]` should give an `IndexError`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying add the values `3` and `"hello"` to each other.  Python is basically telling you that it has no idea what you are trying to do. Since you didn't explain what you think this code should do, we also have no idea what you are trying to accomplish. Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem you are trying to add an element of type `string` to an element of type `int` which is not possible in a regular array.

You can do:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a[2] = a[2] + 3
```

which would give `a[2] = 6`

and for strings you can do:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
a[2] = a[2] + "hello"
```

which would give `a[2] = "chello"`

Comment: Thank you so much >< Have a lovely day

Answer (score 1):

you can fix it turning the `a[3]` value into a string

```
a = [1, 2, 3] 
str(a[3]) + "hello"
```